# Facebook PHP code can't get name

Tags: php, facebook

I'm trying to write PHP code that will display the logged in user's name. So far I've got it to display the user's id but I can't get the name to show.

```
    <?php 

     $app_id = "...";

     $canvas_page = "...";

     $auth_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
            . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page);

     $signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];

     list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 

     $data = json_decode(base64_decode($payload), true);

     if (empty($data["user_id"])){
            echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
     } else {
            echo ("Welcome User: " . $data['user_id']);
     }  

 ?>
```

Changing 'user_id' to 'name' or 'first_name' doesn't show anything.

Comment: Can you print the contents of $data to show what it contains?

Comment: If I just try to echo $data it prints out "array". Using an index like $data[0] just prints a blank.

Comment: Use print_r or other functions to print arrays -- echo won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to hit the `/me` API to get user data.

If using PHP, why don't you check out the [PHP SDK](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/)?

Comment: I tried using the example.php but when I open the page it just shows the github sdk page. Actually anytime I include the "require '../src/facebook.php';" line it just opens that page.

Comment: @Foppy I'm confused. You don't "use" `example.php`, you read the source to see examples of using the SDK. You need to download the SDK to your computer then include the `facebook.php` file. Also note the `fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt` needs to be in the same directory as `facebook.php`

Comment: Turns out I needed to learn quite a bit about cUrl, Perl, and OpenSLL. Also my webhost doesn't allow https which was screwing up everything.

Answer (score 2):

Recommend to use with [Facebook PHP SDK](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk).

You can call like that

```
try {
  $me = $facebook->api('/me');
  print_r($me);
  echo $me['name'];
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
  error_log($e);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is also much shorter and easy to use PHPforFB framework ([http://www.phpforfb.com/en](http://www.phpforfb.com/en/)).

The code looks like this:

```
include(‘phpforfb_framework.php’);
$FacebookAPP = new PHPforFB($structInit);
//Query basic permissions.
if(($res = $FacebookAPP->ForcePermissions('basic')) === FALSE){
    //An error occurred when querying the permissions
    echo "PHPforFB Error: ".$FacebookAPP->lastErrorCode." -> ".$FacebookAPP->lastError;
    exit;
}else{
    //Evaluate the result
    if($res==0){
        //The user declined.
    }else{
        //The user accepted to grant permissions to the application.
        $res = $FacebookAPP->GetUserInfo();
        print_r($FacebookAPP->userData);
    }
}
```